# gsub with awk on a file by name

Tags: bash, awk, gsub

I'm trying to learn how to use awk with gsub for a particular field, but passing the name, not the number of the column on this data:

```
especievalida,nom059
Rhizophora mangle,Amenazada (A)
Avicennia germinans,Amenazada (A)
Laguncularia racemosa,Amenazada (A)
Cedrela odorata,Sujeta a protección especial (Pr)
Litsea glaucescens,En peligro de extinción (P)
Conocarpus erectus,Amenazada (A)
Magnolia schiedeana,Amenazada (A)
Carpinus caroliniana,Amenazada (A)
Ostrya virginiana,Sujeta a protección especial (Pr)
```

I tried

```sh
awk -F, -v OFS=","   '{gsub("\\(.*\\)", "", $2 ) ; print $0}'
```

removes everything between parentheses on the second ($2) column; but I'd really like to be able to pass "nom059" to the expression, to get the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading the first line of your input file (the header line) build an array (`f[]` below) that maps the field name to the field number. Then you can access the fields by just using their names as an index to `f[]` to get their numbers and then contents:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
}
{
    gsub(/\(.*\)/,"",$(f["nom05"]))
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
especievalida,nom059
Rhizophora mangle,Amenazada
Avicennia germinans,Amenazada
Laguncularia racemosa,Amenazada
Cedrela odorata,Sujeta a protección especial
Litsea glaucescens,En peligro de extinción
Conocarpus erectus,Amenazada
Magnolia schiedeana,Amenazada
Carpinus caroliniana,Amenazada
Ostrya virginiana,Sujeta a protección especial
```

By the way, read https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps for why you should be using `gsub(/.../` (a constant or literal regexp) instead of `gsub("..."` (a dynamic or computed regexp).

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. I have made an `awk` variable named `header_value` where you could mention field name on which you want to use `gsub`.

```
awk -v header_value="nom059" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     if($i==header_value){
         field_value=i
     }
  }
  print
  next
}
{
  gsub(/\(.*\)/, "",$field_value)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of above code.

```
awk -v header_value="nom059" '           ##Starting awk program here and creating a variable named header_value whose value is set as nom059.
BEGIN{                                   ##Starting BEGIN section of this program here.
  FS=OFS=","                             ##Setting FS and OFS value as comma here.
}                                        ##Closing BEGIN section here.
FNR==1{                                  ##Checking condition if FNR==1, line is 1st line then do following.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                    ##Starting a for loop which starts from i=1 to till value of NF.
     if($i==header_value){               ##checking condition if any field value is equal to variable header_value then do following.
         field_value=i                   ##Creating variable field_value whose value is variable i value.
     }
  }
  print                                  ##Printing 1st line here.
  next                                   ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  gsub(/\(.*\)/, "",$field_value)        ##Now using gsub to Globally  substituting everything between ( to ) with NULL in all lines.
}
1                                        ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited line.
'  Input_file                            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Creating a separate variable per field (e.g. `field_value`) is OK if you only have 1 field you're interested in but creating an array that maps all field names to their positions (e.g. `f[]` as used in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57893381/1745001) works just as well for this minimal case as it does for cases where you need to access dozens of fields by their names and it lets you easily loop on all fields and/or test for a field name being present if desirable so it's generally the better approach.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you Ed sir for feed back, point noted, will try to implement in future, cheers.